# Errors in Layout Cant figure it out!

Tags: android, eclipse

Please Help.

I'm trying to create a menu that pops up if an android user clicks "menu" on his phone.
and i want on the screen a button so when the user clicks it a sound starts playing for a second or two.
&&
this error keeps popping up in my java class in the part where it says "                public boolean onCreateTutorial(Menu menu) {"

heres my code.

```
package com.Tutorial;

import com.Tutorial.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Tutorial extends Activity {
    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
        mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
        mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound);

        Button SoundButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
        SoundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(1);


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateTutorial(Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }
                      }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.icon:     Toast.makeText(this, "Rate this app on Android Market!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "Name: Wahid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "MeSoundFx Pro on the Android Market! (Coming Soon)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You messed up your code completely. It seems to start that your onClick() method has a onCreateTutorial() method inside, which can't be.

Looks like you messed up on copy/past.

Solution: Follow your code line by line, watch starting and closing brackets and correct your code.

//edit: I am not posting the corrected code, because you should do that by yourself to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Change the onCreateTutorial to onCreateOptionsMenu